# Custom function error to produce a shortcode resulted in white screen of death

Tags: wordpress, shortcode, custom-function

I followed the syntax the best I could to create a shortcode on execution, I got the wsod. Once removed, all was well. But I don't know what is wrong with my code. This code sits inside 'My Custom Functions', a plugin for wp.

In researching how to write a custom shortcode, I discovered instructions here: https://torquemag.io/2017/06/custom-shortcode/ My expertise is in mysql and use mostly plugins in our wordpress website. I am very limited with coding.

```
function last_updated_shortcode {
   $last_updated = $wpdb->get_results( "SELECT MAX(process_time) FROM 
qgotv.last_updated");
    return $last_updated;
}
add_shortcode( 'last_updated', 'last_updated_shortcode' );
```

This shortcode should retrieve a max(datetime value) from a db table so it can be displayed on a page. The query works. The qgotv db is separate from the wordpress db but can be accessed through wp.

Answer (score 0):

Two issues I can see, one is that you have a syntax error in your function. When defining a function in PHP, you need to include the arguments parenthesis: `function my_function(){ /* Do Stuff */ }`. Also, you probably need to reference the `$wpdb` with the global keyword.

You can read up a bit on the [`$wpdb` class](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/wpdb) as well as [creating your own functions](https://www.tutorialrepublic.com/php-tutorial/php-functions.php).

This should get you sorted out:

```
add_shortcode( 'last_updated', 'last_updated_shortcode' );
function last_updated_shortcode(){
    global $wpdb;

    $last_updated = $wpdb->get_results( "SELECT MAX(process_time) FROM qgotv.last_updated");
    return $last_updated;
}
```

Comment: That took care of the WSOD. Thank you very much! But I am not getting the results expected. When I run the query in a SQL window it returns a datetime '2019-08-25 07:43:04' but when I run the function on a wp page listed as: [last_updated], I get the results: Array.

Comment: `$wpdb->get_results()` will return an array. If it's just a single result, you can probably just use [`array_shift()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-shift.php) on it before you return it. `return array_shift( $last_updated );`

Comment: I'm afraid that made the wsod come back. I replaced the entire 'return' line with new 'return array' line you have in your comment. The semi-colon was in place as was the ending }